# Find the matrix representation of linear transformation $T$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $T(1, 1) = (3, 1, 0)$ and $T(0, 2) = (3, 0, 1)$, find the matrix representation of $T$.

So the canonical bases for $\mathbb{R}^2$ are $(0, 1)$ and $(1, 0)$. Starting with those I have

$(0, 1) = a(1, 1) + b(0, 2) \Rightarrow a = b = 0$

$\Rightarrow T(0, 1) = 0 \cdot T(3, 1, 0) + 0 \cdot (3, 0, 1) = (0, 0, 0)$? And same goes for $(1, 0)$. This doesn't seem right...I'm not sure if I approached this problem correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(0,1) = a(1,1) + b(0,2)$$

does not mean that $a=b=0$. It means that

$$0 = 1\cdot a + 0\cdot b$$ **and** $$1 = 1\cdot a + 2\cdot b.$$ The solution to this system of $2$ equations is not $a=b=0$.

Comment: I see. So in that case, $(0, 1) = a(1, 1) + b(0, 2) \Rightarrow a = 0, b = \frac{1}{2}$. And then $(1, 0) = a(1, 1) + b(0, 2) \Rightarrow a = 1, b = -\frac{1}{2}$. So $T(0, 1) = \frac{1}{2}T(0, 2) = (\frac{3}{2}, 0, \frac{1}{2})$ and $T(1, 0) = T(1, 1) - \frac{1}{2}T(0, 2) = (-\frac{1}{2}, 1, -\frac{1}{2})$. So $T$ consists of the columns $(\frac{3}{2}, 0, \frac{1}{2})$ and $(-\frac{1}{2}, 1, -\frac{1}{2})$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Adrian Looks good to me!

Comment: I meant $(\frac{3}{2}, 0, \frac{1}{2})$ and $(\frac{3}{2}, 1, -\frac{1}{2})$. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Write $T$ for the matrix of $T$ and $\tiny \begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\end{pmatrix}$ for the matrix of the vector $(1,1)$, etc. You then have $T {\tiny \begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\end{pmatrix}} = {\tiny\begin{pmatrix} 3\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}}$ etc., so that
$$ T \begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\1&2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 3&3\\1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}. $$
This equation is simple enough to solve, by inverting one matrix. Do you see which one?

By the way, in your attempt, the solution $a = b = 0$ you found is obviously false. A right one would also answer your problem.